# rhive.connect() throws exception

Tags: java, r

I'm new to R-programming. 
I'm trying to connect to hive using `rhive.connect()`.
I understand there could be some mismatch of "org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl" parser. 
How can I resolve this ?

```
ERROR conf.Configuration: Failed to set setXIncludeAware(true) for parser org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl@1f9bb21f:java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:  setXIncludeAware is not supported on this JAXP implementation or earlier: class org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:  setXIncludeAware is not supported on this JAXP implementation or earlier: class org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
        at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setXIncludeAware(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:589)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:1143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:1119)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:1063)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:416)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
        at RJavaTools.invokeMethod(RJavaTools.java:386)
Error: Failed to connect to hdfs://localhost:9000.
```

If my understanding is wrong, help me to understand.

I have noticed `/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf` file is trying getting effected with `R CMD javareconf` command. Is `Makeconf` a configuration file for `R`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved by running below R command line:

```
.jcall("java/lang/System","S","setProperty","javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory","com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl")
```